# Adding notes to places in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to add my own notes to places in Google Maps? I need to find new customers and would like to add notes to placemarks on the map.

Further to that, is it possible to create categories for these places with different colors (e.g., shops=yellow, doctors=red, restaurants=green) to help group them together?

I'm using Google Maps on my browser and smartphone.

Answer (score 5):

yes you can use [Google Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker)

Comment: google map maker is really cool, i've never seen this stuff before

Comment: Interesting tool, unfortunately is not yet available in many countries. Almost all Europe is not included.

Comment: From the link you posted: "Google Map Maker officially closed on March 31, 2017, and many of its features are being integrated into Google Maps."

Answer (score 0):

Agree.
Google Map Maker is a great tool for writing map notes online using the web browser.

If you also want to write map notes on mobile phones/tablets when you do not have an Internet connection, think the Appxis mobile app ([www.appxis.com](http://www.appxis.com)) is a great help as it allows users to download offline maps of any place in the world and write map notes easily on the move both online/offline too.